# Product Model With Stock_QTY Scoped to Size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, scope

I have a functioning, self built e-com web app, but right now the app assumes we have infinite quantity.

It uses line_items and product models.

I am going to add stock_QTY as an attribute to the product

For items that don't have any variants (sizes, colors etc.), the line_item will be created if and stock_QTY is greater than one.

I'm not sure how to deal with sizes though.

Should I create different Products? IE:

```
Shirt.create (name:"small green shirt", color:"green", size:S, stock_QTY:4)
Shirt.create (name:"medium green shirt", color:"green", size:M, stock_QTY:6)
Shirt.create (name:"large green shirt", color: "green", size:L, stock_QTY:1)
```

This seems repetitive, but at least the stock QTY can have some independence. Is there a way to create only one shirt record, with variants, and allow them to have different sizes?

Ideally I'd like

```
Shirt.create(name:"shirt", colors:['red', 'blue', 'green'], sizes: ['s','m',l'])
```

and then be able to do

```
Shirt.where(color => "green").where(size => "L").stock_QTY
=> X number
Shirt.where(color => "green").where(size => "M").stock_QTY
=> Y number
```

This way I have one model, but it can store different quantities depending on the scope of the variants.
Let me know if this is unclear.

Thanks!

*Update*
Product.rb

```
require 'file_size_validator'
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :line_items
    before_destroy :ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
    validates :price, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.01}
    validates :title, :uniqueness => true
    def to_param
      "#{id}_#{permalink}"
    end
    private

    # ensure that there are no line items referencing this product
    def ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
      if line_items.empty?
        return true
      else
        errors.add(:base, 'Line Items present')
        return false
      end
    end
end
```

Here is my Product as it is now.
from seeds.rb

```
Product.create!([
{
    :title => "Liaisons Shirt Green",
    :description => "",
    :has_size => true,
    :price => 24.99, 
    :permalink => "shirt",
    :weight => 16.00,
    :units => 1.00,
    :image => (File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "app/assets/images/dev7logo.png")))

}
])
```

Comment: Can we see your actual implementation of the `Product` model?
It seems you have more a problem with the DB model. There're multiple solution to solve this, but if your app is 'almost done' maybe you prefer the shortest one

Comment: Added Product.rb,  thank you for your interest in helping.

Comment: Not a problem :) I'm trying to understand how your Model is organised. what about that `Shirt` in the first part of the question? Is a subclass of Product? Or is a LineItem?

Comment: I added how the shirts are at the moment in the db.  User chooses size, which belongs to line-items.

Comment: okey, I got the problem. Logically, cart item  or line item should  be responsible what is going to be added on it. It will talk to the product. Product will response if he is more available to be added in that cart. So the validation should be placed on line items. Please have a look at my solutions.

Comment: Ok! So Shirt is a Product, that means that you should not be able to do `Shirt.create`, but only `Product.create` like in the last example. That was confusing me :) In this case, I'm sorry but you're ideally right solution is not possibile, becouse in relational DB there are not `Array` columns type :( As you said, one approach here would be to create a Product for each size/colour combination and use stock_QTY as a field. The BEST approach (and most scalable) would be to manage Sizes and Colours as Models, but this would add 3-4 new tables, so I'm not sure would be interesting for you

Comment: Doh, sorry I oversimplified that... there is no Shirt dmoel XD

Comment: How would I integrate the Sizes and Colors as models?

Comment: Define the Size and Color models, make your actual Product model the BaseProduct model and finally create the Product model which will have 3 external keys (base_product_id, color_id and size_id) and of course the stock_qty field to define all possible configurations with the minimal repetition of information :) this would be the best solution IMO. once on the Mac (I'm on the phone now) I can give you a basic implementation of this 4 models of you need it

Comment: This is the approach I'll take. I'll see how far I get on my own.  I'll mark your answer correct if you post this as one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, my advice is to improve the DB schema to make it more flexible and scalable ;)

Define the Size and Color models (2 new tables), make your actual Product model the BaseProduct model (just renaming the table) and finally create the Product model (new table) which will have 3 external keys (base_product_id, color_id and size_id) and of course the stock_qty field to define all possible configurations with the minimal repetition of information :)!

Just a little help, you're final classes schema should be like:

```
class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Size < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class BaseProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
   # This will have almost all fields from your actual Product class
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   # Ternary table between Color, Size and BaseProduct
end
```

I'm omitting all associations because I like the idea you succeed on your own, but if you need, please just ask :)
This will allows you to do BaseProduct queries like:

```
base_product.colors
base_product.sizes
product.base_product # retrieve the base_product from a product
```

and to keep trace of the quantities:

```
product.stock_qty
product.color
product.size # size and color are unique for a specific product
```

You can also create some helper method to make the creation process similar to the one you'd like to have (as shown in your question).

Comment: I'm progressing, but I have a question... Now I have BaseProducts and Products.  Should every "add-to-cartable-item" be a Product?  Right now, some things that don't have variance (different sizes) are in there as BaseProducts.  So a line_item can either have a base_product_id or a product_id, which I feel like will add a lot of conditional logic to my app (don't really want that)... Should the product model have a lot of duplicate fields and inherit from the base_product?  That seems repetitive, but less work in the long run maybe. Not sure which is the better approach.

Comment: The best thing would be to add only `Product`s to the cart, because otherwise (thus using BaseProduct) you lose the information about the selected color and size.
To manage BaseProduct without both (or only one) sizes and colors, you can introduce special records like `DefaultColor` and `DefaultSize` or `NoColor` and `NoSize` and create just a single Product for those BaseProduct using these special colors or sizes.

Comment: Just to be more clear: `no_color = Color.create!(description: 'no_color', rgba: 'transparent')` and then `Product.create!(base_product: base, color: no_color, ... )`

Comment: Thank you for the help. Ok... I don't want to inundate my index with product variants (ie, showing each product when they are only a different size)... How should I manage this? I could show products where color AND size have the default value (thus, grabbing each record that only has one record) -- as for the products like shirts, I think I'd like to show the baseproduct and then have a line_item create the product_id based on the  size selected from the baseproduct record... does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, you're completely right :)! Just show the `BaseProduct`s in the index, so that users can select one of them. This will prompt a description/detail page allow users to choose for the right size and color (if needed). Finally, as you said, you can add the LineItem based on the specific product_id, so you keep the information about the choose of size/color of the user in the description/detail page ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well I understand the approaches you wanted to deal with. Pretty easy business logic if I understand correctly. So you wanted the following things If I get you correctly:

1. You have so many products
2. You want to add stock count record
3. You wanted to validate the product for selling (line items for cart) if the product available
4. You need to ensure if the product is already in customer's cart when you are deleting that.

So I assumed you already added the stock_qty columns.

Now you need to ensure if the product is available to be added in your cart.

So you need to write your validation in your line_item modem.

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
 # other business logics are here
 belongs_to :product
 before_validation :check_if_product_available

 def check_if_product_available
     # you will find your product from controller, model should be responsible to perform business  
     # decision on them.
     if !self.try(:product).nil? && self.product.stock_qty < 1
         errors.add(:product, 'This product is not available in the stock')
         return false
     end
 end
end
```

This is the approach I believe is the valid way to do. And moreover, rather saving variants in same product model, I would suggest consider designing your model more efficiently with separate variant model or you can utilize the power of self association.

I hope this will help you. Let me know if I miss anything or miss interpret your problem.

Thanks

Comment: Your answer is correct, but only after that @Peege151 will decide to create a new Product record for each size/colour combination. Otherwise, this way, you can't keep track of specific size/colour availability. In his current model, he simply has a unique Product record despite the number of sizes/colours for that Product. This is the real problem

Comment: Thanks for the response @Rubyrider.  My main issue is handling the QTY on a given Product within the scopes of variants like color and size.

Comment: @Peege151 yah you are filtering the product by any scope you need (but thats in different place as I assumed) before you are adding that to line item. :) So you pick the product first and based on the scope and store it [at]product variable (lets assume). Then you do some operation like: [at]product.add_to_line_items which will create the line item. And there line item will verify with my validation methods if the product has the ability to be added as a line item. 
let me know if u understand the flow?